# Error accessing Names in Excel using Interop

Tags: excel, interop

I am programming an application in C# (Visual Studio 2015) and I need to update an .xlsm file.

This file has many formulas, over 1200 names and vba code.

I am using the Interop library and I am able to update some cells and get the relative updated formulas but i have some problem with the Names defined in the Excel.
The program recognizes the names in the Names collection but doesnt let me access some of the names.

When I try to access the value of the cell using its name it produces an exception. 
I dont understand why i can access some of the names and others no.

Besides, in the excel, I can see the Name in the combo but when I select it, the cursor doesn't position over the cell.

In my program I could avoid this problem accessing the cells using the reference instead of the Name, but the vba in the excel uses the names and if i open the file from my app it doesnt work.

I am using this code:

```
excelApplication = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
excelApplication.ScreenUpdating = true;  
excelApplication.Visible = true;
excelApplication.DisplayAlerts = false;   
excelWorkbook = excelApplication.Workbooks.Open(txtFicheroEntrada.Text);
wsDatos = excelWorkbook.Worksheets[1];
wsDatos.Select();

foreach(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Name v in excelWorkbook.Names)
{
    string NombreVar = v.Name;
    //here i found the name BobinadoAT correctly. It exists
    if (NombreVar == "BobinadoAT" ){ Console.WriteLine(NombreVar); }
}

if (wsDatos.Range["BobinadoAT"] != null) //but here this produces an exception 
{
string valorcelda = wsDatos.Range["BobinadoAT"].Value.ToString();
}
```

¿does anyone work with many excel Names? 
¿Am I accessing the names incorrectly?

Comment: always makes sense to give the details of the Exception

Comment: I am capturing the exception but I only see the Message : "Excepción de HRESULT: 0x800A03EC". could i find any help in any property of the exception object? Thanks